# Retain Information over successive Page Releaods in PHP

Tags: php

Here is the Aim of my Program.

1. I Want around 5-6 Circles to be shown on the page, of colors red and green.
2. When, any of the circle is clicked. Its color changes to BLUE.
3. Then, if i click any other circle on the page its color should also change to BLUE, and the circle previously clicked should also show as BLUE.
4. So, if i click all circles one by one, in succesive pageloads, all the circles should show up as blue.
5. And, when a blue circle is clicked, it should show its original color.
6. This loop should continue for-ever, until the page is closed.

This is what i have done till now.

```
define("SIZE", 5); //the no. of circles

 class redblock
     {
     var $color;


         function set_color($data)
     {
         $this->color = $data;
     }
     function get_color()
     {
         return $this->color;
     }
     function image_source()
     {
         $rval2 = $this->get_color();
         echo $rval2;
     }
     function display_block()
     {
         $rval = $this->get_color();
         echo "<img src = '",$rval,"' width=120> </br> " ; 
         }
 }

for ($i=0 ; $i < SIZE ; $i++ ) //INIT color blocks

             { $rb[$i] = new redblock ; }



for ($i=0 ; $i < SIZE ; $i++ ) //color set
{
    if(!isset($_POST[$i.'form']))
    {    
        if ($i % 2 == 0) //even blocks are green
            $rb[$i]->set_color("green.jpg");
        else                    //odd blocks are red
            $rb[$i]->set_color("red.jpg"); 
    }
    if ( $_POST[$i.'form'] == "blue.jpg" )
        $rb[$i]->set_color("blue.jpg");

    if(isset($_POST[$i.'form']))
        $rb[$i]->set_color("blue.jpg");
} ?>



<?php

// BOTH BLOCKS when clicked repeatedly should turn to white and fro.

for ($i=0 ; $i < SIZE ; $i++ ) //display the blocks
{
    echo "<form method ='post'>";
    echo "<input type = 'image' width='120' src ='",$rb[$i]->image_source(),"'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='".$i,"form' value='",$rb[$i]-get_color(),"'>";
        echo "</form>";
    }

?>
```

What Happens, in this code.
1. Suppose, i click Circle 1. It turns to blue.
2. Then i click circle 2, it turns blue, but circle 1 becomes green again. I want circle one to retain the blue color.

Please give me the correct code, or guide me in the right direction. Even, a small help will be largely appreciated.

I have no knowledge of Javascript, etc. I only know PHP and HTML/CSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) variables or set a cookie using [setcookie()](http://php.net/setcookie) and then retrieving it with $_COOKIE on the successive page loads. Either way will get you temporary storage of the values. Sessions are the way to go if you want the values to disappear after the browser is closed. Cookies will persist until they expire or are cleared by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) to store each of the circle's state and use it on successive page loads.

Comment: Weird! I had deleted this answer and had put this as a comment. I wonder how did that change.